# Why does Mockito skip the initialization of the member variable of my abstract class

Tags: java, unit-testing, abstract-class, mockito

I'm trying to test an abstract class and Mockito does not initialize my member variables. Here's a simple example to show you my problem.

This is an abstract class that initializes its 'field' member:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public abstract class Foo {
    private final Collection field = new ArrayList();

    protected Foo() {
        System.out.println("In constructor");
    }

    public boolean isNull(Object o) {
        field.add(o);

        return o == null;
    }

    abstract void someAbstractMethod();
}
```

Here the test class:

```java
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        final Foo foo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);

        Mockito.when(foo.isNull(Mockito.anyObject())).thenCallRealMethod();

        Assert.assertFalse(foo.isNull("baaba"));
    }
}
```

When the test is run it throws a NPE because the variable 'field' is not initialized!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenCallRealMethod%28%29 is not recommended. What do you want to test? If it is the implementation of some methods of Foo, then simply create a subclass. Use Mockito, when you want to verify behaviour or stub method calls.

Comment: As I said to [@david-wallace](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1081110/david-wallace), I want to test the abstract class. My intention of using a mock was to prevent compilation error should the abstract class, or one of its interfaces, change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, when you mock something the created instance is a complete mock, so it makes no sense to initialize the fields as behavior is *defaulted*.

Aside of that, fields can be initialized by a constructor in concrete or abstract classes, as mocks instantiation bypasses the constructor simply because it's a mock, it is even more irrational to initialize them.

Trying to call the real method is usually wrong when using mocks. Instead one should stub the behavior of the mock.

```
Mockito.when(foo.isNull(Mockito.anyObject())).thenReturn(false);
Assert.assertFalse(foo.isNull("baaba")); // assertion always passing
```

I don't know your actual use case but maybe you want a partial mock, with a `spy`. Though that's still considered bad practice as it usually means you need to refactor the code to use composition.

Comment: I expected Mockito to do something it was not designed to do. As discussed with [@David-Wallace](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1081110/david-wallace), I'll create dummy implementation in my tests which I'll have to maintain should  methods be added/removed. Thx

Comment: Is this the expected behavior for static members too? I've tried and Mockito required static members to be initialized, it should skip that initialization also right?

Comment: @dushyantashu static members are initialized by the classloader when the class is loaded. Mockito does not change that.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be mocking the class that you're actually trying to test.  That's not really the idea of mocking.  You mock classes that are outside the scope of your test, and leave the thing that you're testing unmocked.

In this case, you should probably just create a `Foo`, with a dummy implementation of `someAbstractMethod` and test that directly.  No need for any mocking, as far as I can see.

Comment: Indeed, I want to mock the abstract class I'm testing so that the tests won't fail whenever a new abstract method is added to that class (or one of its interfaces). Is that really a bad practice?

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to lay down the law about what's a "bad practice" and what isn't.  But it DOES feel rather like using a chisel as a screwdriver.  It's not what mocks were designed for.  My instinct would be just to stick with testing your own dummy implementation, and add the new methods everywhere they're needed.  I guess it depends on how often you want to add a new abstract method to the class - if it's a frequent occurrence, then Brice's point about refactoring to use composition probably applies.  The answer to your question though is that Mockito was never intended to  ...

Comment: ... initialise fields in its mocks; now armed with that knowledge, go ahead and do your testing in whatever way suits you best.

Comment: You're right... Though, if you don't mind, I'll accept Brice's answer because it clearly talks about the way Mockito works, which would be important for anyone with the same problem.

Comment: Sure.  Brice's knowledge of Mockito is unsurpassed, and his answers here are always clear and eloquent.